# Norm on commutative algebra satisfying square property is submultiplicative

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a commutative algebra and $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm on $A$ such that $\|x^2\|=\|x\|^2$ for all $x \in A$. Show that $\|xy\| \leq \|x\|\|y\|.$

**My attempt:** If I *assume* $$2\|xy\|\leq(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2\tag{1}$$ for all $x,y \in A.$

Then from this I get from all $x,y \in A$ $$\|xy\|\leq 2\|x\|\|y\|.$$
Then replacing $x$ and $y$ with $x^{2^n}$ and $y^{2^n}$, the required result follows.

> However, I'm not able to prove equation $(1).$ I tried using $4xy=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$ but didn't get too far.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: This is Cauchy Schwartz inequality you can look it up for extra references :)

Comment: An algebra often means an algebraic structure such as a vector space or an inner product space

Comment: Actually how do we get $\|xy\|\leq 2\|x\|\|y\|$ from $2\|xy\|\leq(\|x\|+\|y\|)^{2}$?

Comment: @user284331 I first show it for all $x,y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1.$

Comment: Simply fantastic, appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you use $4xy=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$? We have
\begin{align*}
\|4xy\|
&=\|(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2\| \\
&\leq\|(x+y)^2\|+\|(x-y)^2\| \\
&=\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2 \\
&\leq(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2+(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2 \\
&=2(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2,
\end{align*}
and therefore
$$
2\|xy\| \leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2.
$$